# jQuery form validation not being called

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need to validate Name, Room Number, and Phone Number fields in an HTML form. I wrote custom rules for each and called them in the script. But those and the default jQuery rules aren't throwing errors when the input is invalid. Here's my code.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

jQuery.validator.addMethod("firstlastname", function(value, element){
    return this.optional(element) || (/^[a-z]([-']?[a-z]+)*( [a-z]([-']?[a-z]+)*)+$/.test(value));
}, "Please Enter Your First and Last Name");

jQuery.validator.addMethod("roomnumber", function(value, element){
    return this.optional(element) || (/^\d{3}\S{0,1}/.test(value));
}, "Invalid Room Number");

jQuery.validator.addMethod("phonenumber", function(value, element){
    return this.optional(element) || (/^\d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{4}$ | ^\d{10} | ^\(\d{3}\)\d{3}\-\d{4}$/.test(value));
}, "Invalid Phone Number Format");


  $("#my_form").validate({

    rules: {
      name: {
            required: true,
            firstlastname: true
      },

      room_number: { 
            roomnumber: true
      },
      cell_phone: {
          required: true,
          phonenumber: true
      }
    },

    messages: {
        name: {
            required: "First and Last Name is Required",
            firstlastname: "Please Enter Your First and Last Name"
        },
        room_number: {
            roomnumber: "Invalid Room Number"
        },
        cell_phone: {
            required: "Phone Number is Required",
            phonenumber: "Please Enter a Valid Phone Number"
        }
    },

    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if (element.attr("name") == "Name") {
            error.appendTo($("#nameValid"));
        } else if (element.attr("name") == "Room_Number") {
            error.appendTo($("#roomNumberValid"));
        } else if (element.attr("name") == "Cell_Phone") {
            error.appendTo($("#cellPhoneValid"));

        }
    } 
});
});

</script>
```

And here's the HTML

```
<form id="my_form" method="post" >
<p>Name:    </p>
<p>
  <input name="name" style="width: 275px" type="text"/>
  <span id="nameValid"></span>
</p>

<p>Room Number:</p>
<p>
  <input name="room_number" type="text" maxlength="5"/>
  <span id="roomNumberValid"></span>
</p>

<p>Cell Phone:</p>
  <p> <input name="cell_phone" style="width: 192px" type="text" maxlength="13"/> <br/>
<span id="cellPhoneValid"></span>
  </p>
```

I've experimented with different jquery files and jquery validate plugin versions as well and they all allow me to submit invalid input. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: I think this code is only for input validation, and not prevent the form from being submitted

Comment: I have very similar code in another project that does the same thing and is fully functioning. When it throws an error, it prevents the submit action.

Comment: Then it's an homologation error, or something....try to use the other code as a guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root problem is a syntax issue within your `errorPlacement` function.  Like most JavaScript and HTML, the `name` attribute is case-sensitive.

`if (element.attr("name") == "Room_Number")` is never going to work when the `name` is actually `"room_number"`.

Try this instead:

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    if (element.attr("name") == "name") {
        error.appendTo($("#nameValid"));
    } else if (element.attr("name") == "room_number") {
        error.appendTo($("#roomNumberValid"));
    } else if (element.attr("name") == "cell_phone") {
        error.appendTo($("#cellPhoneValid"));
    }
}
```

**Working:  http://jsfiddle.net/8KVHv/**

Although, I'm not really sure why you have a very verbose custom `errorPlacement` callback when it appears to function exactly the same as the default:  http://jsfiddle.net/8KVHv/2/

You could use [the `wrapper: "span"` option](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) if you'd rather have your error text inside of a `span` instead of the default `label` elements.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/8KVHv/3/

---

**BTW**:  You probably don't need to write a custom method for phone numbers.  Maybe just use the `phoneUS` rule within the [`additional-methods.js`](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js) file.

**See: http://jsfiddle.net/8KVHv/1/**